# Cross Domain Ajax Get Request using jsonp- PHP File on External Server for SQL-Queries

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, callback, jsonp

I have to get my smartphone-application to work until tomorrow and after hours of work I can't solve it on my own.

**Important part of the PHP:**

```
    $sql = "SELECT `player_id`, `intro`, `level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `sectask1`, `sectask2`, `sectask3` FROM `matrix` WHERE `matrix`.`player_id` = '$id';";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);




    $results = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $results[] = $row;

};


 $json = json_encode( $results);
header("Content-type: application/json");  
echo( $_GET['callback'] . ' (' . $json . ');' );

?>
```

**My Javascript Function:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slogan").click( function(){
         console.log("EnterMatrix");

   $.ajax({type: "GET",

    url: 'http://192.168.141.98/getmatrix.php',

   dataType: "jsonp",

   crossDomain: true,

   success: function(data) {

console.log("intro");
                var users=JSON.parse(data);
               console.log(data);


                var intro = users[0].intro;
                 var level1 = users[0].level1;
                 var level2 = users[0].level2;
                 var level3 = users[0].level3;
                 var sectask1 = users[0].sectask1;
                 var sectask2 = users[0].sectask2;
                 var sectask3 = users[0].sectask3;


                 if(intro==0){
             console.log("clicked2");
    $("#matrix_introduction").show(300);}
    else{
     $("#matrix_introduction2").show(300);}

    },

    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    alert('error ' + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
   }
     });

   });
    });
```

What is Wrong - I am thankful for every hint!

I already tried a hella lot of solutions! Maybe it is something obvious?

Thanks :)

Comment: You don't need to call `JSON.parse()`, that's done automatically.

Comment: Thanks and done. Of course it doesn't help for the whole thing.

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Content type should be `application/javascript`, but I don't think it should make a difference.

Comment: I had an error "timeout".  The php returns the following: [{"player_id":"1","intro":"0","level1":"0","level2":"0","level3":"0","sectask1":"1","sectask2":"1","sectask3":"1"}]

Answer (score -1):

```
 $json = json_encode( $results);
 header("Content-type: application/json");  
 echo( $_GET['callback'] . ' (' . $json . ');' );
```

replace this code with

```
 $json = json_encode( $results);
 echo $json;
```

Comment: That's JSON, not JSONP.